# LDAP bind PHP connection reset

Tags: php, ldap, connection, bind

I'm quite new to the topic and after reading a bunch of other articles here, I could eliminate a lot of errors in my little project, but now I'm stuck.

I'm trying to bind to a test LDAP Server, that I found here on Stack Overflow (https://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/). I am using XAMPP on my local machine and want to use User and Password from a HTML page (I know, this is not a very safe way of doing it).

I could verify the connect and the variables passed through html. But I do not get any sign of a successful.

My code connecting and binding is:

```
<?php

// using ldap bind

$username = $_POST['uname']; 
$ldaprdn  = "cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com"; // ldap rdn or dn uid=$username,ou=mathematicians,
$ldappass = $_POST['psw'];  // associated password

// connect to ldap server
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389")    
or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if ($ldapconn) {



    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);


    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP Bind successful...";
    } else {
        echo "LDAP Bind not successful...";
    }
}
?>
```

Now I would expect to see either a message "success" or a message "no success". But all I get as a response from the server is:

```
The connection was reset

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

Now I do not know if there is a problem on the server side, a problem within my code, a problem with my php (version 7.1.33, ldap enabled in php.ini) or just a general problem with my understanding of binding to LDAP.